# Need help understanding the WHERE argument of Allen Browne's ConcatRelated function in MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, concatenation

I have a query (qryClassInstructor) that shows the courses being taught in a given academic term and their instructors:

> SELECT tblClasses.ClassID, tblClasses.SubjAreaID,
>   tblClasses.CourseID, tblClasses.AcadTerm,
>   tblInstructors.InstructorID
>   FROM tblInstructors RIGHT JOIN (tblClasses LEFT JOIN tblClassInstructor ON tblClasses.ClassID = tblClassInstructor.ClassID)
>   ON tblInstructors.InstructorID = tblClassInstructor.InstructorID;

Because some classes have multiple instructors, this query returns multiple lines for a given class, each showing one of the instructors.

> 1, MATH, 100, 2015SP, Smith, J.
>   1, MATH, 100, 2015SP,
>   March, A.

I'd like to create a field that concatenates these instructors, so I'm using Allen Browne's ConcatRelated function.  Here is the SQL I'm using:

> SELECT qryClassInstructor.CourseID, qryClassInstructor.AcadTerm,
>   ConcatRelated("InstructorID","qryClassInstructor","ClassID = " &
>   [ClassID],"CourseID","; ") AS [Instructor(s)]
>       FROM qryClassInstructor;

This generally works (the concatenation happens), but I'm still getting multiple lines for any course that has multiple instructors.

> 1, MATH, 100, 2015SP, Smith, J.; March, A.
>
> 1, MATH, 100, 2015SP, Smith, J.; March, A.

I will be honest that I really don't understand the WHERE argument part of the function (new to VBA), so would love some help if that's my problem.

I understand others have asked about this function as well, but I have yet to see the WHERE argument explained well and would appreciate insight on it.  Also, is it a problem that our InstructorID field uses commas and periods (eg, "Smith, J.")?  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this and it should eliminate the dupes:

> SELECT DISTINCT qryClassInstructor.CourseID, qryClassInstructor.AcadTerm, ConcatRelated("InstructorID","qryClassInstructor","ClassID = " & [ClassID],"CourseID","; ") AS [Instructor(s)] FROM qryClassInstructor;

The **DISTINCT**  operator forces Access to eliminate the dupes based on the fields chosen in your **SELECT** statement.

Comment: One more quick question about this. When I try to reverse this to show the Instructor with concatenated courses they're teaching, I end up with the same course being concatenated multiple times for the same term ("MATH 100, MATH 100") instead of (MATH 100, MATH 109).

Comment: This is the SQL:
SELECT DISTINCT qryClassInstructor.InstructorID, qryClassInstructor.AcadTerm, ConcatRelated("CourseCatID","qryClassInstructor","ClassID = " & [ClassID],"CourseCatID"," / ") AS Courses
FROM qryClassInstructor
WHERE (((qryClassInstructor.InstructorID)<>"IsNull"))
ORDER BY qryClassInstructor.InstructorID;

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about that function or what it does, so I wouldn't know why it works in one case but not the other.